# Error in __func__

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>    
char* __func__ = "hello";
void myfunc(void)
{
      printf("%s\n", __func__);
}
int main()
{
  myfunc();
}
```

The above snippet gives error: `expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘__func__’`. Why?

Comment: `__func__` is probably defined as a macro somewhere, such that when the token is replaced with its definition, a parenthesis or identifier is needed.

Answer (score 9):

You know that `__func__` is a predefined identifier (at least as of C99, see [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zvm/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r9.cbclx01/predefined_identifiers.htm) for details)? Why are you using it? I'm guessing you get the error at the `__func__` definition line, because of that.

Comment: +1 In fact ALL identifiers containing double underscores are reserved. Which to the OP means YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED TO USE THEM!

Comment: @Neil, ... not allowed to use them, but for their well defined purpose :)

Comment: @Jens Yes, that's more accurate. You certainly are not allowed to create them or initialise/assign to them.

Comment: @Neil: I believe it's all identifiers *starting* with a double underscore.

Comment: @Oli Well, in C++ it is all identifiers containing one. I can't be arsed trolling through the C standard to see if it is the same, but  I suspect it is. See 17.4.3.1.2 in the current C++  standard.

Comment: @Oli and Neil: I misspoke - in C it's identifiers that start with an underscore which is followed by another underscore or uppercase letter (C99 7.1.3).  So identifiers with double underscores in other places are apparently reserved only in C++.

Comment: @Neil, @Michael: Interesting.  I did not know that C++ differed in this regard!

Answer (score 0):

Technically the behaviour is undefined as per C99 because you explicitly declare `__func__` .

> J.2 Undefined behavior
> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
> ...
>
> The identifier `__func__` is explicitly declared (6.4.2.2).

And it is known that undefined behaviour means anything can happen [and that includes compilation error as well]